# Saving rows which were created first

Tags: java, oracle

Below is the state of my table `DUMMY_TBL` 
[image]

I am writing a query to save the rows which were created first and delete the rest. The grouping can be done based on the LOCAL_ID, So in this case the query should keep first and the fourth row and delete the rest. If we look in the `WHENCREATED` column, we can get the information about the creation detail of the rows.

So far I have done is

```
select min(WHENCREATED),LOCAL_ID from DUMMY_TBL group by local_ID;
```

But this gives me only the min `WHENCREATED` date and it LOCAL_ID. However, I am not sure how to proceed further.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how are you using two database at once ?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: if you have a unique identifier for each row in the table you can just delete from table except for those rows you have extracted with your query

Comment: @Zeromus I have a unique identifier but when I include that in the query i.e.  select min(whencreated),LOCAL_ID, AB_COURSE_ENROLLID from DUMMY_TBL group by local_ID; but it gives me error in group by clause.
AB_COURSE_ENROLLID is the primary key

Comment: or you ca use those values directly like in Andrew S answer

Comment: @Zeromus Andrew S query may not work sometime, So if I could retrieve the AB_COURSE_ENROLLID somehow then the query will fetch the exact result.

Answer (score 1):

From the query which fetches the records to keep:

```
select local_id, min(whencreated) as earliest
from dummy_tbl
group by local_id;
```

then combine to delete all other records except for those records to keep:

```
delete from dummy_tbl
where (local_id, whencreated)
not in
(    
    select local_id, min(whencreated) as earliest
    from dummy_tbl
    group by local_id
);
```

keep in mind that for a bigger table this may not work since the in clause have a size limit

Answer (score 0):

Gather MinDate / LOCAL_ID combinations and join them to the actual table.

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT min(WHENCREATED) AS MinDate
        ,LOCAL_ID
    FROM DUMMY_TBL
    GROUP BY local_ID
    )

DELETE
FROM DUMMY_TBL
JOIN CTE c ON c.MinDate != WHENCREATED
    AND c.LOCAL_ID = LOCAL_ID
```

Comment: I have a unique identifier in the table, I think if I delete it with that then it will delete the accurate rows.However, when I execute the query it gives me error  select min(whencreated),LOCAL_ID, AB_COURSE_ENROLLID from DUMMY_TBL group by local_ID; but it gives me error in group by clause. AB_COURSE_ENROLLID is the primary key